# Julia websockets - what is readguarded and writeguarded?

Tags: websocket, julia

I noticed in the Julia websockets API, there are functions called readguarded and writeguarded. What exactly are these for?

The docs seem to explain that these are used to log errors, but is that all that they do?

> When using readguarded or writeguarded, errors are logged with @debug
>   statements. Set the logging level of the logger you use to 'Debug', as
>   in 'examples/count_with_logger.jl'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The designers of Julia's Socket routines decided to have the read and write socket routines throw an exception on failure, similar to the exception thrown by the file open routines on error. The readguarded and writeguarded routines are socket read and write routines wrapped in try-catch, so that they can return an error on exception as below, from the WebSockets.jl source code:

```
function readguarded(ws)
    data = Vector{UInt8}()
    success = true
    try
        data = read(ws)
    catch err
        @debug err
        data = Vector{UInt8}()
        success = false
    finally
        return data, success
    end
end
```

The @debug statements are then used to log errors with use of the Logging library, since those errors are otherwise caught and hidden (by design) within the readguarded and writeguarded routines.